# How to modify an array?

Tags: c, arrays, steganography

I'm currently trying my hand at steganography with some .wav files.

What I want to do is write a program that opens the sound file into an array and then modify said array, but that's where I'm stuck.

Currently I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "scc110wav.h"

int main ()
{
    unsigned char *soundData = LoadWavAudioFile("3stepoct.wav");

    int byte;

    for (byte = 0; byte <= 5554944; byte++){
        printf("%d\n", soundData[byte]);
    }
}
```

All I can do currently is print the array, but with no way of changing the values of the array. I know I won't need to print the array in the final thing, especially since it's so big, but I just wanted to get a feel for the file so that I can change the array values to ASCII values without the listening being able to detect much of a change in sound.

Comment: Well, isn't `soundData[index] = 42;` good enough?

Comment: I love "int byte;" it's like "long string;"

Comment: I'm confused, what exactly is the problem? Is there a reason you can't just write to it with `soundData[byte] = 50;`, or some unsigned char value?

Answer (score 3):

`soundData` is not `const`, so you can access bytes of your stream using the `[]` operator and do whatever you want with this data.

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, you are confused where you need to change so that wav file can be playable.
If this is the problem you can learn all about the wave file format from below link

[Click here to learn Wave file format](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/)

and you can change in data portion by leaving the other details regarding chunk size, etc. intact.

Answer (score 0):

When you are printing the `soundData[byte]` in the `for` loop using `%d` specifier, you are printing the ASCII value of the character stored in the `soundData[byte]`.So, you can easily access and modify the data stored in `soundData[byte]` at any point of time just like you do with normal arrays.Besides its just `unsigned char *` so nothing's stopping you from modifying anything in the array.

You might want to consider changing the datatype of `byte` from `int` to `long long` because `5554944` used in the `for` loop, is beyond the `int` max storage value limit. So, basically you will be rolling over and over.

Once you get to understand how to access the data in the audio file, what you should really look at is a good steganography algorthm to implement on your input stream. Simplest one would be LSB-based algorithms.